# Merge 'remote' and 'remote-control'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-cleanup

From the questions using the tags, [remote](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote) (x17) and [remote-control](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-control) (x53) cover the same area. Hence my suggestion:

- merge [remote](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote) to [remote-control](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-control)
- make the former a synonym to the later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.  I'm going to double check right now for any "remote access" questions that might need to be retagged.

**Edit:** [remote-control](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-control) and [remote-access](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-access) are still a bit messy.  I'm not sure if we should merge them or what.  I don't think there are many questions about using devices as TV remotes so fortunately that isn't complicating things :)